# Spring Security: How to handle a User object with lazy-loaded JPA fields during authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, second-level-cache

I'm working on a Spring Boot application with spring-data-jpa (hibernate) and spring security. My user object looks like this:

```java
@Entity(name = "User")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public User implements UserDetails {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private UUID id;

   @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String username;

   @Column(name = "passwordHash", nullable = false)
   private String passwordHash;
   
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(
      name = "User_Roles",
      joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "User_ID")],
      inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "Role_ID")]
   )
   private Set<Role> roles;
 
   // constructor, getters, setters
   // hashCode() & equals() based on id
}
```

This object is fetched in our `AuthenticationServletFilter` and subsequently stored in the `SecurityContext`. As you can see, the `roles` collection is currently fetched in an eager fashion. The `Role` itself consists of ID and a name.

I'm now faced with the following issue:

- Since authentication happens on every request, I need to use the **Hibernate Second-Level Cache** to cache the user objects.
- Hibernate seems to refuse to do that because of the eagerly loaded `roles` field. In the debug logs, I can see SQL queries which fetch the user object again and again for every authentication.
- Loading the roles in a lazy fashion is difficult, because it means that the processing which occurs in the `AuthenticationServletFilter` would have to be `@Transactional`. If it's not, any code which accesses `user.roles` from the `SecurityContext` later on will receive a `LazyInitializationException`. But marking a request filter as `@Transactional` feels wrong from a software architecture point of view.

What's the standard course of action for a situation like this? I could imagine that this is a pretty standard scenario.

I tried to make the `roles` collection lazy-loaded, but that resulted in `LazyInitializationException`s later down the line. Having it loaded eagerly fixes that, but seems to prevent the hibernate second level cache from caching and/or reusing the user object. Marking the `AuthenticationServletFilter` as `@Transactional` feels wrong.

Comment: Why do you think this is related to the eagerly loaded `roles`? Also, depending on what exactly you are doing you probably need to employ the query cache not the 2nd level cache.

Comment: @JensSchauder I know for a fact that hibernate is repeatedly loading the same user by ID (once per request). I read online that eager fetching doesn't play well with the second level caching mechanism, which is why I assumed that this is the cause. I might be wrong here; debugging caching behavior turned out to be quite a challenge.